# SSRS formatting the table structure

Tags: mysql, sql, c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table DemographicDetails showing population information. The fields are

- ID - Unique id field (autoincrement)
- Population - integer
- SurveyDate - datetime field
- City - varchar field indicating city
- State - varchar
- Region- South/North
- Country

I need to  have  report to display the population details in below format

```
India              Current Yr Figure        PreviousYr Figure   
State_1            X,XX,XX,XXX              XX,XX,XXX 
State_2            X,XX,XX,XXX              XX,XX,XXX 
State_3            X,XX,XX,XXX              XX,XX,XXX
```

I have tried with the below query:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (99.99) PERCENT 
            Population, City, State, SurveyDate, Region, Country, 
            CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, surveydate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()))THEN 'CurrentYear' ELSE NULL END AS CurrentYear, 
            CASE WHEN (DATEPART(yyyy, surveydate) <> DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())) THEN 'LastYear' ELSE NULL END AS LastYear
    FROM DemographicDetails
    ORDER BY City)  
SELECT Population, City, State, Region, Country, SurveyDate, 
       CurrentYear, LastYear, COALESCE (CurrentYear, LastYear) AS DateStatus
FROM cte AS cte_1
```

And in the report textbox I have given the expression as:

```vb
iif(Fields!DateStatus.Value="CurrentYear",Fields!Population.Value,0)
```

In first textbox and in second box the expression is:

```vb
iif(Fields!DateStatus.Value="LastYear",Fields!Population.Value,0)
```

However, my result is similar to this:

```
India       Current Yr Figure     PreviousYr Figure          
State_1     value1                0
State_1     0                     value2
State_2     value3                0 
State_3     value4                0
```

But I need it as follows:

```
India               Current Yr Figure         PreviousYr Figure          
State_1             value1                    value2
State_2             value3                    0 
State_3             value4                    0
```

i.e for state_1 value1 and value2 in same row.

Comment: Can you post the entire query? You probably just need a left join.

Comment: @JacobGoulden Where is the left join to be included i mean in which query. Also I have posted the complete script.